# Compare two text files files and return what lines and columns the 1st difference is on

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got a program which compares two text files and prints the difference to a new text file, but I want to modify it so it just prints out the line and column where the first difference occurs. Here is what I have so far:

```
f1 = open("file1.txt", "r")
f2 = open("file2.txt", "r")

fileOne = f1.readlines()
fileTwo = f2.readlines()

f1.close()
f2.close()
outFile = open("file3.txt", "w")
x = 0

for i in fileOne:
   if i != fileTwo[x]:
      outFile.write(i+" <> "+fileTwo[x])
   x += 1
 outFile.close()
```

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look into `with` when dealing with files.  It auto-closes them for you.  Here is a reference: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Comment: Have you considered using [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as f1:
    lines1 = f1.readlines()

with open("file2.txt", "r") as f2:
    lines2 = f2.readlines()

bound = max(len(lines1), len(lines2))
for idx, line1, line2 in zip(xrange(bound), lines1, lines2):
    if line1 != line2:
        diff_line = idx
        break

bound = max(len(line1), len(line2))
for idx, c1, c2 in zip(xrange(bound), list(line1), list(line2)):
    if c1 != c2:
        diff_char = idx
        break

print "first difference is on line {0:g} and character {1:g}".format(diff_line, diff_char)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `break` after the first match.

```
for i in fileOne:
    if i != fileTwo[x]:
        outFile.write(i+" <> "+fileTwo[x])
        break
    x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate` and `itertools`. This solution will load only two lines(one from each) at a time into memory.

```
from itertools import izip, dropwhile, izip_longest
with open("abc1") as f1, open("abc2") as f2:
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(izip(f1, f2), start=1):
        if x != y:
            print "line number is", i
            column =next(dropwhile(lambda(i, c1, c2):c1==c2,
                         ((i, c1, c2) for i,(c1, c2) in enumerate(izip_longest(x, y)))))[0]
            print "column number is", column
            break
```